# OCMock a Class method to call back the passed block with custom Data

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock

I do have a class that handles all my network communication like this:

```
typedef void (^ networkEndblock) (NSArray *, NSError *);

@interface NetworkAPI : NetworkBase

+ (void) doSomeNetworkAcion:(networkEndblock) endBlock;

@end
```

I use the above code like this (I do not want to get into irrelevant details here)

```
- (void) runMyProcess:(SomeEndBlock)proccesEnded{

  // Bussiness logic


  // Get Data from the web
  [NetworkAPI doSomeNetworkAcion:^(NSArray *resultArray, NSError *error){

   // Check for error. if we have error then do error handling
   // If no error, check for array.
   // If array is empty then go to code that handles empty array
   // else Process data                                 

   }];
}
```

In my test method I want to trigger runMyProcess to test, I do not want it to go and hit the network, I want to control that and set cases to make it return an error, empty array ...etc. I know how to use SenTest and it is MACROS but I do not how to fake my network API.

I looked into stubs and expect but I got confused if I can do what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class mock `[NetworkAPI doSomeNetworkAction:]` and use an `andDo` block.

```
// This is in the OCMock project but is really useful
#import "NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.h"

// Whatever you want for these values
NSArray *fakeResultArray;
NSError *fakeError;

id networkAPIMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NetworkAPI.class];
[[[networkAPIMock expect] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    networkEndBlock endBlock = [invocation getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:2];
    endBlock(fakeResultArray, fakeError);
}] doSomeNetworkAction:OCMOCK_ANY];
```

Also, I would capitalize `NetworkEndBlock` in my typedef as it will make your code easier to read for others.

Comment: Works fine iOS 7, I had to add NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.h, but crashed in iOS 6.1, any idea?

Comment: Hard to say. Is there something in your endBlock that isn't iOS6 compliant? What does the crash log say?